# Обновить часть формы

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Есть форма вывода сообщения, в ней же можно изменить некую часть посредством тега селект, который скидывает в базу значение. Вопрос: как обновить страницу без мета рэфреш, а еще лучше обновить только этот кусок кода?
Код выглядит примерно так:

```
... таблица
    <td><!-- нужно обновить этот вывод, остальное не важно:) --><?echo $s['s']; ?><br />
    <form method=post>
    <select name="s">
    <option value=s1>s1</option><option value=s2>s2</option><option value=s3>s3</option>
    </select>
    <input type=submit>
    </form>
    <?
    //подключение к БД бла бла бла
    if(!result) {
    echo mysql_error(); } else {
    echo "все чих пых!"; }
    ?>
```

Comment: Т.е идея в том что пользователь выбирает чтото из option'ов select'a и сразуже чтото подгружается на страницу, я правильно понял?

Comment: угумс, просто по дефолту надо страницу еще раз перегрузить, чтобы пользователь увидел результат обновления в базе. Можно конечно вывод засунуть в к примеру if(постпустой) вывод else пост не пустой стукнуть в базу получить "свежачок"... но это имхо бред...<br /> не вижу тайного смысла в осмысленном быдлокодинге.

Comment: а что такого в конструкции if(empty($_POST))? я не понимаю собственно откровенно говоря, в чем тут "быдлокодерство" то? темболее что в зависимости от этих данных как я понимаю формируются, грубо говоря, 2 разных вида... Это логическое разделение кода на true и false... Раз вам так хочется то единственный вариант который я вижу при использовании select'a - ловить innerHTML option'a на onclick и аяксом дергать, но зачем такие сложности?..<br>
Чтобы ненадо было еще раз страничку перезагружать вы можете сделать сами в своем серверном коде, а не выдумывать чертичто :)

Comment: то есть нормально будет, что будет выполняться по сути 2 запроса в базу? за 1 значением?? если предположить что это будет делать 2 человека, то нормально.. а если 2000? а если одновременно? так зачем лишний раз грузить скрипт? но если конечно другого варианта нет...
<br /><br />
пример, Вы же когда сюда пишете, вы же не обновляете страницу после поста, Вы сразу видите результат своей, так сказать "работы"

Comment: резонно...напишите что либо в ответ.. с меня + и правильный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы о чем вообще? Вопрос количества запросов в базу здесь вообще причем? Т.е. по вашему 1 скрипт = 1 запрос или как, я просто не понял вашей мысли...
Если где-то и выполняется лишний запрос на сервере то это проблема серверного кода но никак не формы и конструкции if(empty($_POST))...

Откровенно говоря мне просто кажется что вы чтото неправильно написали (толи по незннию толи по какойто другой причине) на сервере и теперь ищете как "спрятать" проблему вместо того чтобы сделать все по нормальному... И даже если так я вам выше написал как такое делается js'ом, вперед :)